# What does Mythic Speed do?

Tags: dresden-files, fate

I don't have the book in front of me at the moment, but a part of the power Mythic Speed states something along the lines of "Opponents don't get to make checks against you."  What does this mean?  Do NPCs (and other PCs) just never get to see a creature with Mythic Speed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Here's what Mythic Speed does.

- You always go first in a conflict.
- All Athletics checks are at +3, including dodging. Sprinting boosts that to +6.
- You can keep up with a moving vehicle without any problem.
- You can move up to three zones without a penalty when moving as part of another physical activity.
- No one ever gets a bonus to spot you when you're using Stealth, regardless of your speed. (*I think this might be what you're thinking of in your quote.*)

All this is from page 178 of **DF: Your Story**.

Comment: I actually like your answer better. I'm always torn when quoting rules - how much to put in? In this instance, I think you actually addressed the whole question "What does Mythic Speed do?" better. **And** you sneaked yours in first, too!

Comment: So what does it mean by "they don't get a bonus?"  Does that mean that they don't roll and just use their base skill, do they roll and not use their base skill?  Do you roll and get their base skill, but ????

Comment: @DForck42 It's usually the case that moving disrupts your Stealth, giving people a bonus to their Alertness rolls to try and spot you unless you Skulk. (p.143) At Mythic Speed, they *don't* get any bonuses of that kind. Think of it as denying them a circumstance bonus they would otherwise get.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're talking about is this, from YS p.178:

> **Like the Wind**. No one ever gets a bonus to spot  you when you’re using
>   Stealth, no matter how  fast you’re moving.

Which just means what it says - no bonuses to spot you when you're trying to not be seen. Not "nobody ever sees you."